# Will these objects be collected by GC?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, observer-pattern

Consider the following java code

```
public class PlayerView implements IPlayerListener
{
    public Player player;

    public PlayerView()
    {
        player = new Player();
        player.listener = this;
    }

    public void onPlayerEvent()
    {

    }
}

public class Player
{
    public IPlayerListener listener;

    public void foo()
    {
        //do something then
        if(this.listener != null)
        {
            this.listener.onPlayerEvent();
        }

    }
}

public interface IPlayerListener
{
    public void onPlayerEvent();
}
```

Here I have a PlayerView and Player. The Player needs to report events to the PlayerView so I made an interface called IPlayerListener which Player may have a reference for a PlayerListener object to report events to.

(I know in java this is not the best way to create events, but I don't really need "many listener" to use the default "addEventListener" pattern)

**Question #1: When PlayerView object is set to null, will both the PlayerView and Player object be collected by GC?**

If yes, then proceed to the following code

```
public class PlayerView implements IPlayerListener, IPlaylistListener
{
    public Player player;

    public PlayerView()
    {
        player = new Player();
        player.listener = this;
        player.playlist = new Playlist();
        player.playlist.listener = this;
    }

    public void onPlayerEvent()
    {

    }

    public void onPlaylistEvent()
    {

    }
}

public class Player
{
    public Playlist playlist;
    public IPlayerListener listener;

    public void foo()
    {
        //do something then
        if(this.listener != null)
        {
            this.listener.onPlayerEvent();
        }

    }
}

public class Playlist
{
    public IPlaylistListener listener;

    public void bar()
    {
        //do something then
        if(this.listener != null)
        {
            this.listener.onPlaylistEvent();
        }
    }
}

public interface IPlayerListener
{
    public void onPlayerEvent();
}

public interface IPlaylistListener
{
    public void onPlaylistEvent();
}
```

Here I have added a third class, Playlist class, which Player has also a reference for a playlist object.
Also the Playlist should have a listener/observer. And in this case the PlayerView is also the Playlist listener.

**Question #2: When PlayerView object is set to null, will these objects be collected by GC?**

If the Answer #2 is NO then please proceed

```
public class PlayerView implements IPlayerListener, IPlaylistListener
{
    public Player player;

    public PlayerView()
    {
        player = new Player();
        player.listener = this;
        player.playlist = new Playlist();
        player.playlist.parentPlayer = player;
    }

    public void onPlayerEvent()
    {

    }

    public void onPlaylistEvent()
    {

    }
}

public class Player
{
    public Playlist playlist;
    public IPlayerListener listener;

    public void foo()
    {
        //do something then
        if(this.listener != null)
        {
            this.listener.onPlayerEvent();
        }

    }
}

public class Playlist
{
    public Player parentPlayer;

    public void bar()
    {
        //do something then
        if(this.parentPlayer != null)
        {
            if(this.parentPlayer.listener != null)
            {
                if(this.parentPlayer.listener instanceof IPlaylistListener)
                {
                    ((IPlaylistListener) this.parentPlayer.listener).onPlaylistEvent();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface IPlayerListener
{
    public void onPlayerEvent();
}

public interface IPlaylistListener
{
    public void onPlaylistEvent();
}
```

Here I switch the playlistListener reference with a reference to the parent Player, and instead of calling the playlistListener directly, checked if the playerListener is also a PlaylistListener (Or both interfaces could be merged into one)

**Question #3: Will the previous code solve the problem and all objects get collected?**

Or should I better use the second code block and find the right time in PlayerView object (like before the PlayerView object is removed from its parent view) and at least call "player.playlist.listener = null;".

Comment: By the way in the Playlist class, I'm going to need a reference for its parent Player object. Should I use WeakReference<T> instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to realize that it is theoretically impossible to predict when an object will actually be garbage collected.  And more specifically, setting a field to `null` will not cause it to be collected.  Rather, it may cause it to become unreachable, and hence *eligible* for garbage collected.  That means that it *may* be collected in some following GC run, but not necessarily the next run.  (And note that even calling `System.gc()` is NOT guaranteed to cause eligible objects to be collected.  The JVM is free to ignore the `gc()` call.)

Note: reachability is all about whether the object could still be accessed by some live thread.  If a thread could follow a chain of references to reach some object, then it is reachable.  Naturally, the chain needs to start with a reference variable that the thread can access; e.g. a static variable or an local variable or argument on the thread's stack.

---

So to your specific questions:

> Question #1: When PlayerView object is set to null, will both the PlayerView and Player object be collected by GC?

The code doesn't either create a `PlayerView` instance or have a `PlayerView` variable that could be nulled.  I also note that the Player and PlayerView objects point to each other.  This reference cycle does not directly affect reachability.  Though it does mean that if either of the objects are reachable then both are.

So if we assume that there is just one `PlayerView` variable ... and no `Player` variable ... then assigning `null` to the variable will cause both objects to become unreachable and hence eligible to be collected.

> Question #2: When PlayerView object is set to null, will these objects be collected by GC?

Again, with the same caveats, when the last reachable reference to the `PlayerView` is nulled (or when it becomes unreachable), all three objects will be eligible to be collected.

---

Some advice:

1. You are probably worrying too much about when and how the objects get reclaimed.  It most likely doesn't make the slightest difference.
2. Explicitly nulling things to cause them to be collected is generally a waste of time.
3. There is no need to worry about reference cycles in Java.  Java GC is not based on reference counting, and there is no need to break cycles to make GC work.

Comment: *And note that even calling System.gc() is guaranteed to cause eligible objects to be collected.* missing negation?

Comment: I'm aware that setting and object reference to null doesn't cause an object to be collected, my questions should have been "are these objects eligible to be collected" as you have said.

Comment: Still, I'm not sure I've got your answer, In my code I assume we have, say in the main function "PlayerView pView = new PlayerView();" this way we have one PlayerView instance, which in its constructor creates a Player object. Will then assigning pView to null will cause both object to be eligible to be collected?

Comment: @user1729952 - Assuming that there are no other variables containing references to any of these objects, then the answer is Yes.